# Using the same Controller for User and Admin Layouts in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, layout, view

I have a **StudentController** used for **Student** and **Admin** users and there is an **Index** page in the **Controller**. **Admins** use **StudentController** and list grades of students on an **Index** page having **_AdminLayout** and students use **StudentController** and list their grades on the same Index or another page having **_StudentLayout**. As far as I know using the same **Controller** for both type of users is true as the operations is related to Students. However, I am not sure should I create a new method in the same **Controller** or use another **Controller**. Any idea regarding to this issue? What do you do for such a similar scenario when using two different **_Layout** page or the same Controller's **View**?

Comment: If its the same controller method and the same view, you could conditionally set the layout using `@{ if (someCondition) { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml"; } else { Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StudentLayout.cshtml"; } }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke The layout can be selected according to the condition you mentioned. On the other hand, I think the same View (Index) can only be used by rendering two different partialview into it (for admin and for student). Because the Views for these two users are different. Is this approach true?

Comment: In that case (if you need 2 different views, the each view can have a different layout associated with it (and the the controller, you could use `if (someCondition) { return View("AdminView", model); } else { return View("StudentVIew", model) }; (or just have 2 separate methods in the controller)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I think creating 2 methods with no condition would be much more clean and faster :) Regards...